# GeoTools Dynamic Layer

Tags: cartography, geotools, rendering, dynamic

I need to change the features of a MapLayer in real-time but I don't know how I can update/refresh/repaint the layer on the map without having to remove it and add it again (which creates flickering).

```
map.removeLayer(pathML);
SimpleFeatureCollection pointsFC = createFeatureCollection(points);
pathML = new MapLayer(pointsFC, pathStyle);
map.addLayer(pathML);
```

Do you know a better way to update the Layer rendering?

Comment: Any GeoTools nerds out there?

Comment: most of the GeoTools' nerds already answered this question on the mailing list :-) http://osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/Double-buffering-bufferstrategy-etc-td6391216.html

Comment: Thread is gone? Where have all the GeoNerds gone? Why isn't Swing supported? How else does one port GIS visuals to an end-user?

Comment: @cj5 too many questions youg padawan

Answer (score 4):

This actually makes the geotools faq page for gt-swing. The real answer is to use JMapPane as an example (because that is what it is) and build your own widget using a number of layers for a fast response. See the [flying saucer demo code](https://github.com/KueenLau/geotools-tike/blob/8fd5342340b75e7c43dbd89d6e93efcf835b99d9/demo/example/src/main/java/org/geotools/demo/swing/FlyingSaucer.java).

You may also find the spatial indexed back feature collections useful in providing a fast experience if you don't mind holding your data in memory.

- http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/unsupported/swing/faq.html