# Update Layer as I create new Features

Tags: geotools

Already read [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10212/geotools-dynamic-layer) but can't found any solution since many links are broken and coudn't find the "Flying Source Demo".

My goal is to create a empty Layer at first and them going to put Features inside it as new data are comming from a thread.

This is what I did:

First create some globals because I'll access them from different functions:

```
private MapContent map;
private SimpleFeatureType VESSEL;
private SimpleFeatureBuilder vesselFeatureBuilder;
private DefaultFeatureCollection vesselCollection;
private GeometryFactory vesselGeometryFactory;
private Layer vesselLayer;
private JMapPane mapPane = new JMapPane();
```

... now I'll start creating the geometries:

```
private void initGeometries() {
    SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
    builder.setCRS(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);
    builder.setName("Vessel");
    builder.add("coordinates", Point.class);
    builder.length(15).add("shipName", String.class);
    builder.add("mmsi", Long.class);
    builder.add("lat", Float.class);
    builder.add("lon", Float.class);
    builder.add("bearing", Integer.class);
    this.VESSEL = builder.buildFeatureType();
    this.vesselFeatureBuilder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder( this.VESSEL );
    this.vesselCollection = new DefaultFeatureCollection();
    this.vesselGeometryFactory = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory(null);
}
```

well, at this point I tried to create the Layer but seems the `this.map.addLayer( this.vesselLayer );` don't allow to put an empty Layer so I tried to create the Layer in a separate function only when the first Feature arrives:

```
private void createVesselLayer() {
    Style style = SLD.createPointStyle("Circle", Color.BLACK, Color.BLUE, 0.3f, 15);
    this.vesselLayer = new FeatureLayer( this.vesselCollection, style );
    this.vesselLayer.setTitle("Vessel Layer");
    this.map.addLayer( this.vesselLayer );    
}
```

now the code to create the Feature and put it in the Layer:

```
private void createVesselFeature( float x, float y, long mmsi, int bearing ) {
    
    System.out.println( x + "," + y);
    
    Point point = this.vesselGeometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(x, y));
    this.vesselFeatureBuilder.set("coordinates", point);
    this.vesselFeatureBuilder.set("lat", y);
    this.vesselFeatureBuilder.set("lon", x);
    this.vesselFeatureBuilder.set("bearing", bearing);
    this.vesselFeatureBuilder.set("mmsi", mmsi);
    SimpleFeature aVessel = this.vesselFeatureBuilder.buildFeature("Vessel");
    this.vesselCollection.add( aVessel );

    // Is the Layer ready?
    if( this.vesselLayer == null ) createVesselLayer();
}
```

I have a Thread working on collect data from a source and then call `createVesselFeature`.

After all I have only ONE feature (blue circle) on my map and no new Features are shown although no errors are displayed.

Already tried `this.mapPane.repaint();` with no success.

My question is: how can I refresh the Layer on map to show new added features?

***EDIT 1***

Strange... when I call `this.vesselCollection.getCount()` right after `this.vesselCollection.add( aVessel );` it always tell me it have just one Feature so I think the problem is not the Layer itself.

***EDIT 2***

Oops !! Found this: [Adding features to featureCollection does not update the map](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/419519/adding-features-to-featurecollection-does-not-update-the-map)

But the accepted answer didn't solved my problem. reseting the MapPanel just bring the map back to original state and this is not the behaviour I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the main error and the "inconvenient" problem:

First, my error with the SimpleFeatureCollection was I need to give an UNIQUE ID when creating a Feature, so the part

`SimpleFeature aVessel = this.vesselFeatureBuilder.buildFeature("Vessel");`

was changed to

`SimpleFeature aVessel = this.vesselFeatureBuilder.buildFeature( String.ValueOf(mmsi) );`

Now `this.vesselCollection.getCount()` is giving the correct number o Features.

Second problem: "The Map Update".

When I zoom in or out, I can see the new Features on the map, which leads me to think that the panel needs to be updated, as Ian said [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/419519/adding-features-to-featurecollection-does-not-update-the-map).

But the only solution I see was call `this.mapPane.reset();` just after adding a new Feature but it will bring my map back to the start condition ( global view ) and I loose the zoom I was (actually I can't zoom anymore because it is constantly backing to initial zoom).

A little hack was to "shake" the map:

```
        this.mapPane.moveImage(1,1);
        this.mapPane.moveImage(-1,-1);
```

So the final working result is here:

```
    private void createVesselFeature( float x, float y, long mmsi, int bearing ) {
        if( !this.mapIsReady ) return;
        System.out.println( mmsi + " " + x + "," + y);
        Point point = this.vesselGeometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(x, y));
        this.vesselFeatureBuilder.set("coordinates", point);
        this.vesselFeatureBuilder.set("lon", x);
        this.vesselFeatureBuilder.set("lat", y);
        this.vesselFeatureBuilder.set("bearing", bearing);
        this.vesselFeatureBuilder.set("mmsi", mmsi);
        
        // Give the Feature a unique ID
        SimpleFeature aVessel = this.vesselFeatureBuilder.buildFeature( String.valueOf( mmsi ) );
        
        
        this.vesselCollection.add( aVessel );
        if( this.vesselLayer == null ) createVesselLayer();
        
        // Shake the map to update without a flick ou reset:
        this.mapPane.moveImage(1,1);
        this.mapPane.moveImage(-1,-1);
        
    }
```

***EDIT***

Ian Turton showed me a much more elegant way to achieve this, but as I said in comments, it causes the map to blink at every update.

According to him, you need to extend the FeatureLayer class:

```
public class UpdatableLayer extends FeatureLayer {

  public UpdatableLayer(FeatureCollection collection, Style style) {
    super(collection, style);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  }

  public void updated() {
    fireMapLayerListenerLayerChanged(MapLayerEvent.DATA_CHANGED);
  }
}
```

Replace this:

`this.vesselLayer = new FeatureLayer( this.vesselCollection, style );`

by this:

`this.vesselLayer = new UpdatableLayer( this.vesselCollection, style );`

and call `this.vesselLayer.updated();` instead `this.mapPane.moveImage(-1,-1); this.mapPane.moveImage(1,1);`

I'll keep the `moveImage()` just because this blink, but I recommend the Ian's method if you don't care about this.

Comment: a better way to do it is to use the event system - https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190820/adding-multiple-points-to-same-layer-using-geotools

Comment: Hi @IanTurton. My event system is the Observer triggered when a new Feature arrives from an AIS (NMEA) device. It is appart from GeoTools. The question here was not about "when" but "how".  I don't like it very much the fact of creating a new warapper class or to add complexity in my code. As you said in the answer you posted: ```You can directly call redraw on your JPane``` I sympathize more with this method and I've done this by calling ```moveImage()```. I found this way much simpler and cleaner than adding new classes and code only to update the screen if we left asside the "when".

Comment: I think the answer of my whole question is ```this.mapPane.moveImage(1,1);  this.mapPane.moveImage(-1,-1) ```  to update the map image to reflect the new added features. I'm already taking care of the "when" part.

Comment: but if you send the `MapLayerEvent.DATA_CHANGED` event to the MapPane it will automatically redraw itself with out you needing to jiggle the map

Comment: @IanTurton I tried your method just now and it worked too. Although it is more elegant, it is causing a little flicker in my map and I dislike it. For those who come here I say that both ways work, but I opted to use ```moveImage```purely by choice. I confess that Ian's method is much more elegant and makes use of best practices.

Comment: I'm not sure why it would flicker in one case and not the other as they should be doing much the same thing. I'll try take a look over Easter