# How to manually draw a line in Geotools Map Viewer example application

Tags: geotools

I would like to digitize a LineString in a "temporary" layer in GeoTools MapViewer example. I know that this is not a specific GeoTools problem I have, rather a java swing problem. But I think someone has done something like this in the GeoTools mapView example, already.

My problem is that I add a mouseListener to the button, then I add a mouseListener in the DrawLine class (for the mapPane) to collect the digitized coordinates within the mapPane. When I start the function, by clicking the draw-button, I can digitize points with the mouse. For now, I'm stopping digitizing by moving the mouse outside the mapPane.
The problem with this is that each time I digitize a point I will start a new line procedure. This results in (with 4 digitized points) 4 "TempLineLayer"-layers with 1 line in each layer. First lineString 4 vertices, second lineString = 3 vertices, etc.

How shall I handle the mouseListeners?

I have added a button in the toolbar:

```
 btn = new JButton("Draw");
        toolBar.addSeparator();
        toolBar.add(btn);
        btn.addActionListener(e -> mapFrame.getMapPane().setCursorTool(new CursorTool() {
            @Override
            public void onMouseClicked(MapMouseEvent ev) {
                DrawLine dl = new DrawLine();
                dl.collectLineCoords();
            }
        }));
```

Then I have my DrawLine class with a mouse listener to collect all the digitized coordinates:

```
public class DrawLine implements MouseListener{
int x,y;
ArrayList <DirectPosition2D> positions = new <DirectPosition2D> ArrayList();

public void collectLineCoords() {
    MapView.mapFrame.getMapPane().addMouseListener(this);
}

static void drawTheLine(Coordinate[] coordinates) {
    SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder b = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
    b.setName("LineFeature");
    b.setCRS(MapView.map.getCoordinateReferenceSystem());
    b.add("line", LineString.class);
    final SimpleFeatureType TYPE = b.buildFeatureType();
    SimpleFeatureBuilder featureBuilder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(TYPE);
    GeometryFactory geometryFactory = 
          JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory(JTSFactoryFinder.EMPTY_HINTS);
    LineString lineString;
    lineString = geometryFactory.createLineString(coordinates);
    featureBuilder.add(lineString);
    SimpleFeature feature = featureBuilder.buildFeature("FeatureLineString");
    List<SimpleFeature> featureCollection = new ArrayList<>();
    featureCollection.add(feature);
    Style style = SLD.createLineStyle(Color.red, 2.0f);
    Layer layer = new FeatureLayer(DataUtilities.collection(featureCollection),
        style);
    layer.setTitle("TempLineLayer");
    MapView.map.addLayer(layer);
    MapView.mapFrame.getMapPane().repaint();
}
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    x = e.getX();
    y = e.getY();
    DirectPosition2D pos = calculateWorldPos(MapView.mapFrame.getMapPane(),e);
    positions.add(pos);
    // Put a marker at each digitized point
    Graphics g = MapView.mapFrame.getMapPane().getGraphics();
    g.fillRect(x-3, y-3, 6, 6);
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    Coordinate[] coordinates = new Coordinate[positions.size()];
    for(int i=0; i <positions.size(); i++) {
        coordinates[i]=new Coordinate(positions.get(i).x, positions.get(i).y);
    }
    MapView.mapFrame.getMapPane().removeMouseListener(this);
    drawTheLine(coordinates);
}
private DirectPosition2D calculateWorldPos(MapPane pane, MouseEvent event) {
    AffineTransform tr = pane.getScreenToWorldTransform();
    DirectPosition2D pos = new DirectPosition2D(event.getX(), event.getY());
    tr.transform(pos, pos);
    pos.setCoordinateReferenceSystem(pane.getMapContent().getCoordinateReferenceSystem());
    return pos;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you end up with many layers because you create and add a new layer on every `mouseExit` - I think this will work though detecting a double click to end would be nicer.

```
class DigitizerAction extends MapAction{
    public DigitizerAction(MapPane mapPane){
        this(mapPane, false);
    }
    public DigitizerAction(MapPane mapPane, boolean showName){
        String toolName = "Draw";
        super.init(mapPane, toolName, ZoomInTool.TOOL_TIP, ZoomInTool.ICON_IMAGE);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){getMapPane().setCursorTool(new Digitizer());}
}


class Digitizer extends CursorTool {
    SimpleFeatureBuilder featureBuilder;
    GeometryFactory geometryFactory;
    ArrayList<Coordinate> positions = new ArrayList<>();
    List<SimpleFeature> features = new ArrayList<>();
    Style style;
    FeatureLayer layer;

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    boolean enabled = false;
    public Digitizer(){
        this.setEnabled(true);
        SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder b = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
        b.setName("LineFeature");
        b.add("line", LineString.class);
        SimpleFeatureType TYPE = b.buildFeatureType();
        featureBuilder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(TYPE);
        geometryFactory =
                JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory(JTSFactoryFinder.EMPTY_HINTS);
        style = SLD.createLineStyle(Color.red, 2.0f);
    }

    void drawTheLine(ArrayList<Coordinate> coordinates) {

        LineString lineString = geometryFactory.createLineString((Coordinate[]) coordinates.toArray(new Coordinate[0]));
        featureBuilder.add(lineString);
        SimpleFeature feature = featureBuilder.buildFeature("FeatureLineString");
        features.add(feature);
        getMapPane().getMapContent().removeLayer(layer);
        layer = new FeatureLayer(DataUtilities.collection(features),style);
        getMapPane().getMapContent().addLayer(layer);
        positions = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMouseClicked(MapMouseEvent e) {
        if(!isEnabled()) return;
        DirectPosition2D pos = e.getWorldPos();

        positions.add(new Coordinate(pos.x, pos.y));
        // Put a marker at each digitized point
        Graphics graphics = (Graphics2D) ((JComponent) getMapPane()).getGraphics().create();
        int x = e.getX();
        int y = e.getY();
        graphics.fillRect(x - 3, y - 3, 6, 6);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMouseExited(MapMouseEvent e) {
        this.setEnabled(false);
        drawTheLine(positions);
    }

}
```

By providing a `DigitizerAction` class we can reduce the buttons action to `btn.addActionListener(new DigitizerAction(mapFrame.getMapPane()));` and by extending `CursorTool` rather than `MouseListener` (and in general `MouseAdapter` is better) we don't have to roll our own transforms etc.

The main trick is to store the temporary layer and to make sure to remove it and re-add it when we add a feature to the list. You could also look this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/456683/update-layer-as-i-create-new-features) to see a better way to do it, but as you won't have many hand drawn features I suspect this way will be fine.

Comment: I've written a [blog post](https://blog.ianturton.com/geotools/2023/05/08/drawing-on-a-geotools-map.html) describing this tool in more detail and linking to a [small project](https://gitlab.com/ianturton/geotools-tools) with a full working example.